# JavaScript RegEx - Capturar texto entre caracteres específicos

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo el siguiente texto:

> Hola, llamaba para pedirte el -b-favor- de que lleves los -b-niños- a la -b-escuela-

Cómo puedo con Javascript capturar el texto que esté dentro de **-b-** ... **-** y pues que , sin importar si hay texto pegado como por ejemplo: **hola-b-Sofía-**

Sólo lo que hay dentro. Pues es que quisiera convertir dicho texto en negrita, cursiva o tachada.

Algo así como:

> Hola, llamaba para pedirte el **favor** de que lleves los **niños** a la **escuela**.

Había encontrado una expresión regular que funcionaba pero lo hacía sólo en PHP, no conozco mucho acerca de las expresiones regulares.

Bueno, teniendo en cuenta que se permite el uso de guiones dentro de -b-... - quisiera saber qué método es más perspicaz o eficiente, pero, explicando por qué, claro. Y me gustaría saber en que circunstancias es mejor **indexOf** y qué otras cuales **RegExp**

### Respecto a la Respuesta de Mariano

La expresión regular funciona muy bien, aunque sólo funciona si el contenido no tiene guiones dentro del mismo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como se puede ver en **fav-or**.

Pienso que esta expresión regular es aún más compleja de lo que normalmente se ve. Siendo una string: "Uso muchos --- porque -- soy - rebelde -.-."

Entonces quedaría:

**-b-Uso muchos --- porque -- soy - rebelde -.-.-**

Ahora bien, debe haber una regla en la que se indique que siempre debe buscar el **último guión** existente **antes** de otro **-b-**; No el primero, según la expresión regular dada, hace **match** a la primera ocurrencia.

Luego de ello si no se halla ese "último", no hay **match** y por lo tanto queda texto normal. Y gracias por ser el vaquero más rapido del oeste :v

### Respecto a la respuesta de Montoro

Suena muy bien el hecho de "hacerse la vida más complicada" en ocasiones o quizá todo el jodido tiempo, porque por lo general le encuentro problema a todo.

La solución con **indexOf** es más rápida en ejecución que **RegExp**, aunque en cuanto a manejo de código es un poco complejo.
No comprendo el uso de algunos **-1** (Es que no entiendo mucho). Suena algo loco, pero realmente funciona aún con uso de guiones dentro.

Y Jajaja, por lo general uso JQuery :)

Comment: He añadido dos pequeñas notas explicando el por qué del -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se puede utilizar [`replace( regexp, reemplazo)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/-b-([^-]+)-/g
```

y reemplazándolo por `<b>$1</b>`

```js
var texto = "Hola, llamaba para pedirte el -b-favor- de que lleves los -b-niños- a la -b-escuela-",
    regex = /-b-([^-]+)-/g,
    reemp = "<b>$1</b>",
    resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

resultado.innerHTML = texto.replace(regex,reemp);
```

```html
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

**Descripción:**

- `-b-` - coincide con el texto literal.
- `([^-]+)` Grupo 1 - coincide con:

  - `[^-]+` - 1 o más caracteres que no sean un guión (`-`).
- `-` - coincide con el texto literal
- Modificador: `g` - Busca *todas* las coincidencias, no sólo la primera.

El grupo 1, además de coincidir con el texto que está entre guiones, también crea una captura. Al reemplazar, `$1` contiene el valor de esa captura.

---

**Evitar tags HTML dentro de la sintaxis:**

Asimismo, dentro de la sintaxis utilizada `-b-`...`-` no debería haber etiquetas HTML, para no "*romper*" la estructura. Una forma posible de evitarlo, sería coincidiendo con estructuras que no tengan ningún `<`, usando el regex:

```
/-b-([^-<]+)-/g
```

Cualquiera de estas expresiones funcionan en cualquier dialecto de regex *basados* en Perl (*Perl-like regex*), por lo que funcionará en JavaScript, PHP, o cualquiera de los lenguajes comúnmente utilizados.

---

**Incluir guiones dentro de la sintaxis:**

Y si quisiéramos complicarlo un poco más: ¿cómo haríamos para permitir guiones dentro del texto en negritas? Podríamos pedir que se escapen con una `\`. En ese caso usaríamos:

```
/-b-([^-<\\]*(?:\\.[^-<\\]*)*)-/g
```

Esta estructura utiliza la técnica conocida como *[unrolling the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)*, haciendo que se incluya a la `\` dentro de los caracteres no permitidos como *normales*, y luego coincidiendo con una barra seguida de cualquier caracter (`\\.`) y más caracteres *normales*.

#### Código Final:

```js
var texto = String.raw`Hola, llamaba para pedirte el -b-fav\-or- de que lleves los -b-niños- a la -b-e\-s\-c\-u\-e\-l\-a- hoy`,
    regex = /-b-([^-<\\]*(?:\\.[^-<\\]*)*)-/g,
    reemp = "<b>$1</b>",
    resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

resultado.innerHTML = texto.replace(regex,reemp);
```

```html
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

---

### Respuestas a lo editado en la pregunta:

> quisiera saber qué método es más perspicaz o eficiente

No voy a contestar a la pregunta general, ya que está basada en opiniones, pero sí comparar con [la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/37551/127), que es excelente y recomiendo votarla +1. Y vale aclarar que las implementaciones propuestas buscan resultados diferentes (estamos comparando peras con bananas, ver el punto más abajo).

Si tomamos la comparación general, y para los ejemplos utilizados, se observan diferencias de aproximadamente 9% (en el orden de los 6μs), algo que para JavaScript no llamaría relevante. No obstante, todo depende del texto que se esté comparando. Por ejemplo, si tomamos un texto más largo (6 párrafos), podemos obtener resultados con aproximadamente **el doble de eficiencia con regex** (comparación en **[JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/es-so-q-37541)**). Y probablemente también se puedan orientar las pruebas a textos que beneficien a `lastIndexOf()`.

> sólo funciona si el contenido no tiene guiones dentro del mismo

Esto no es correcto. Tal cual se plantea en esta respuesta, para permitir guiones dentro de la sintaxis, se deben escapar con una barra invertida (`\`).

[image: regex101.com mostrando que funciona con "-b-fav-or"]

[<kbd>Demo en regex101.com</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/tZ3q6Q/1)

> debe haber una regla en la que se indique que siempre debe buscar el **último guión** existente **antes** de otro **-b-**; No el primero

**¿Por qué creo que no conviene buscar la última ocurrencia de un guión?** Creo que es una [decisión equivocada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37541/expresiones-regulares-de-javascript-capturar-texto-entre-caracteres-espec%C3%ADfico#comment63486_37551) buscar la última ocurrencia, ya que no permite *cerrar* efectivamente una sintaxis. Consideremos este ejemplo:

```
-b-Título:-
Y ahora en el texto no tengo forma de usar un guión porque sino -acá- 
lo tomaría como el fin de las negritas
```

Si esto fuese la sintaxis utilizada en las publicaciones de SO, no podríamos utilizar guiones luego de las últimas negritas, ***no tendríamos forma de cerrarlas***. Si se utilizara en un texto ingresado por el usuario, no sabría cómo documentar el uso. En cambio, creo que es mucho más eficiente (y más comúnmente utilizado) pedirle que los escape **`"-b-por fav\-or-"`**.

De todas formas, si aún se busca que coincida con la última ocurrencia, pediría que se aclare en la pregunta cómo se puede usar un guión luego de las últimas negritas.

> Pienso que esta expresión regular es aún más compleja de lo que normalmente se ve

Es un mito que una expresión regular más larga sea menos eficiente, que se escucha muchas veces, pero que no deja de ser falsa y muchas veces es justamente lo opuesto. De hecho, la técnica utilizada es muy común, y puede leerse acerca de ésta con más detalle en:

- [Section 6.7. Unrolling the Loop](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.482.1.45/1/) en el libro "Mastering Regular Expressions" de Jeffrey Friedl.
- [Unrolling the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) (el artículo previamente referenciado).
- [Mimic an Alternation Quantified by a Star](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-tricks.html#staralt) (rexegg.com)
- [Using regexes, how to efficiently match strings between double quotes with embedded double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17043605/5290909) (SO)
- [Regex match anything up to word - without non-greedy operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33895861/5290909) (SO)

**Nota:** podría haberla presentado más abreviada, como `/-b-(([^-\\]|\\.)*)-/g` pero preferí incorporar una versión mucho más eficiente, y de mayor calidad (acá más largo es más eficiente).

Básicamente consiste en usar:

```
normal* ( especial normal* )*
```

Donde ***normal*** son todos los caracteres excepto `-`, `\` y `<`, y ***especial*** es cualquier caracter precedido de una barra invertida, para que coincida con `\-`.

Mecanismo:

1. se intenta que coincida con cualquier caracter normal `[^-<\\]*`, todo lo que se pueda,
2. y a partir de ahí, intenta coincidir con un escape `\\.`
   seguido de más caracteres normales `[^-<\\]*`
3. Repite el punto (2) cuantas veces sea necesario (por cada escape presente en el texto).

> Y gracias por ser el vaquero más rapido del oeste

No fue mi intención :-) Creo en la calidad por sobre el resto de las cosas.

Comment: Mariano, no nos das tiempo a los demás a preparar nada :P

Comment: Tus respuestas de regex siempre son buenas.

Comment: Oie calmate viejo... :v

Comment: Pregunta editada..

Comment: @MáximaAlekz y edité en respuesta a tu edición.

Comment: Ahora entiendo un poco más sobre mi pregunta, y pues lo de los escapes, suena realmente interesante. Pues, necesitaré texto largos algunas veces, y me interesa más la eficiencia aunque pues a veces no es "tan notorio". Muchas gracias por la explicación,

Comment: @MáximaAlekz el tiempo de ejecución al comparar texto, siempre dependerá de contra qué se lo compare. El motivo de por qué está solución es más eficiente con textos más largos es porque se barren casi 1 sola vez cada carácter al reemplazar. Y para incrementar más la velocidad, podrías declarar el regex fuera de la función, y reutilizar la misma variable en cada llamada.

Answer (score 3):

Sé que la pregunta pide a gritos expresiones regulares, y que usarlas te van a simplificar mucho la vida (la [solución de Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/37545/250) es muy elegante y apenas ocupa una sola línea)... pero a veces me gusta complicarme la vida :P

Las expresiones regulares son potentes y flexibles... pero eso también las hace lentas. Si estás buscando una cadena en concreto, `indexOf` va a funcionar también. Basándome en eso, he hecho un pequeño algoritmo que, dentro de un bucle y de manera secuencial:

- Busca la cadena `-b-` y la sustituye por `<b>`
- Busca el siguiente `-` y lo sustituye por `</b>`

> Nota: `indexOf` devuelve la posición (índice) donde comienza la **primera** aparición de la subcadena buscada. Si no se encuentra, devuelve -1. Por ejemplo: la cadena "`hola caracola`". Si hacemos `.indexOf("ola")`, el resultado va a ser 1, que es el índice donde aparece por primera vez la subcadena buscada (recuerda que en JavaScript, la primera posición es 0). Y si hacemos  `.indexOf("adios")`, el resultado va a ser -1, porque la cadena buscada no se encuentra.

El código no es muy bonito ni es tan limpio como la solución de Mariano, pero haciendo [pruebas con JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/testregexvsindexof12345), parece que su rendimiento es comparable.

Éste sería el código:

```js
var texto = "Hola, llamaba para pedirte el -b-favor- de que lleves los -b-niños- a la -b-escuela-",
    ini = 0,
    pos = 0,
    texto2 = "",
    resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

while ((pos = texto.indexOf("-b-")) > -1) { 
  var posguion = texto.indexOf("-", pos+3);
  texto2 += texto.substring(ini, pos) +"<b>"+ texto.substring(pos+3, posguion) +"</b>";
  texto = texto.substring(posguion+1);
}

resultado.innerHTML = texto2;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

---

Edición: Mariano me comentó que el código tenía un problema si la cadena no se cerraba correctamente (si había un `-b-` sin el `-` después)... y tenía razón. Así que cambié un poco el código para que se realizase una comprobación adicional y así evitar un bucle infinito.

El resultado se ve así:

```js
var texto = "Hola, llamaba para pedirte el -b-favor- de que lleves los -b-niños- a la -b-escuela-",
    ini = 0,
    pos = 0,
    texto2 = "",
    resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

while ((pos = texto.indexOf("-b-")) > -1) { 
  if ((posguion = texto.indexOf("-", pos+3)) > -1) {
    texto2 += texto.substring(ini, pos) + "<b>" +  texto.substring(pos+3, posguion) + "</b>";
    texto = texto.substring(posguion+1);
  } else {
   texto2 += texto.substring(ini, pos) + "<b>"  +  texto.substring(pos+3) + "</b>";
    texto = texto.substring(pos+3);
  }
}

resultado.innerHTML = texto2;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Asume que si has dejado un `-b-` sin su cierre, entonces es negrita hasta el final de la frase. Y los resultados en [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/soes-compare-regex-vs-indexof) parece que siguen siendo comparables.

[Máxima Alekz comentaba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37541/expresiones-regulares-de-javascript/37551?noredirect=1#comment63482_37551) correctamente que mi código no permitía guiones internos. Una solución para que si los permita sería atravesar la cadena hacia atrás en lugar de hacia adelante. Para ello en lugar de utilizar `indexOf`, usaríamos `lastIndexOf`.

> Nota: `lastIndexOf` devuelve la posición (índice) donde comienza la **última** aparición de la subcadena buscada. Si no se encuentra, devuelve -1. Por ejemplo: la cadena "`hola caracola`". Si hacemos `.indexOf("ola")`, el resultado va a ser 10, que es el índice donde aparece por última vez la subcadena buscada. Y si hacemos  `.indexOf("adios")`, el resultado va a ser -1, porque la cadena buscada no se encuentra.

Lo que hace el algoritmo ahora es buscar el último `-b-` de la cadena y enlazarlo con el último `-` que se encuentre después de ese. Si no se encuentra ningún guión, se considera que el fin de cadena es el final de la negrita.

El código se vería así:

```js
var texto = "Hola, llamaba para pedirte el -b-favor- de que lleves los -b-niños -y niñas-- a la -b-escuela-",
    ini = 0,
    pos = 0,
    texto2 = "",
    resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

while ((pos = texto.lastIndexOf("-b-")) > -1) { 
  if ((posguion = texto.lastIndexOf("-")) > -1 && posguion > pos+3) {
    texto2 = "<b>" +  texto.substring(pos+3, posguion) + "</b>" + texto.substring(posguion+1) + texto2;

  } else {
    texto2 = "<b>" + texto.substring(pos+3) + "</b>" + texto2;
  }
  texto = texto.substring(0, pos);
}

texto2 = texto + texto2;
resultado.innerHTML = texto2;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Y aquí los resultados en [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/soes-compare-regex-vs-indexof2), que siguen siendo similares a los de arriba.

Comment: Pero si quiero usar guiones adentro?

Comment: usar guiones adentro va a ser un problema. Una posible solución sería decir que `- ` (con un espacio detrás del guión) va a ser el cierre de negrita, pero no sé si eso es lo que buscas

Comment: @MáximaAlekz ¿cómo diferencias un guión dentro de la cadena de negrita del guión de cierre de la negrita? Definir esa diferenciación es el 90% del problema.

Comment: Creo que no entiendo a dónde va la pregunta..

Comment: Supongo que sería dentro de -b-... -  el último guión sería el cierre. Supongo, creo que es una pregunta algo técnica..

Comment: @MáximaAlekz creo que ya veo lo que dices. Es como lo que pone Mariano al final de su respuesta, ¿no?

Comment: Pues sí, no es la primera ocurrencia de - la que cierra, es la última.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz ahora ya permite "guiones internos"

Comment: Pregunta editada :)